# Save jquery modified page permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to save **modifications made on a HTML page(modifications made with JQuery), PERMANENTLY!** I have read that this thing gets possible by sending an **Ajax call and saving it in a table in a database**, but what do you actually save in the database? The URL of the page? And what do you retrieve back in the Ajax call so that your modifications actually stay on the page?

This is a Spring MVC based web application, in case this information is needed.

I have no clue how to start or if to start trying saving it, because I have also read that this thing might not be possible, as we're talking about Client-Side modifications.

Modification that I am trying to make:
    function versionOne() {

```
    $('#title').addClass('text-center');
    $('#title').css({"margin-top":"0px","color":"black", "font-size":"45px"});
    $('#title').append('<hr>');
    $('#content').addClass('col-md-6');
    $('#content').css({"margin-top":"80px","font-size":"20px", "text-align":"center"});
    $('#picture').addClass('col-md-6');
    $('#picture').css({"border-radius":"25px", "margin-top":"50px"});

}
```

I'd be grateful for some suggestions!
Thanks :)

Comment: DOM modifications with jQuery, JavaScript or any other client-side language are only cosmetic, and won't be permanent. What changes are you trying to make? Perhaps they can be achieved with a server-side language, such as PHP?

Comment: Well all the changes done with javascript/jquery is temporary, if you do DOM manipulation and refresh the page then you will find that page has rendered in its default view. But you can use localstorage some sort of but this is  not a proper solution for this. Instead you would like to work with Node js that would be easy for you.

Comment: @Ben Pearl Kahan, I modify for example the position of a container or style up the text or images with css, from jquery, I have updated my question and put an example of the changes that I am making.

Comment: Are you just trying to save the DOM state?  Would copying and pasting out of the console be acceptable or are you trying to make an app that remembers all changes made on a page previously?

Comment: @Grallen, I am trying to make an app that remembers all changes made. This is ow it should work: User clicks on an Edit button, chooses from a list and presses a radio button, that calls a Javascript method which does the modifications and after clicking a save button, these should remain in place, even after I refresh the page.

Comment: similar to myspace? would recomment storing the javascript code in a seprate field. keep in mind it will run afresh when you put the page back together so any variables will have to be set again as javascript state in the browser is not html format

Answer (score 0):

Saving the whole page won't work in most cases since it's very hard to also save the JavaScript state. So while you can save a static copy of the page without JavaScript with `$('html').html()`, that doesn't get you very far (or causes more trouble than it's worth).

What you want is "preferences". The site should remember some specific values. The usual approach is to load the preferences from the database before the server sends the page for the client. Apply them to the elements of the page and send the result to the browser. That way, the page looks as expected when the user sees it.

When the user changes these settings, use JavaScript to update the page and send the changes as AJAX requests to the server to persist them in the database.

When the user returns to the page, the code above will make sure that the page now looks as before.

Comment: I understand, I have also thought of that approach, but my question is, in what do I send my changes through Ajax request, I mean do I send the url of the page? This question might seem a rather ordinary, but I am just a starter in web development.

Comment: Send the name of the radio button to the server via AJAX when the user clicks it. On the server side, you need a method which accepts the AJAX request and writes the name into the database for this user (they are logged in, right?) When you render the page again, make sure the correct radio button is selected. In the JavaScript of the page, check which button is selected in the `ready()` callback and call the function to update the styles once.